# Delete the last substring

Tags: c++, string

I have a task. There are 2 strings: S and s. I need to remove the last substring of S, that is the same with s. 
For

```
S = [123 234 789 123]
         s = [123]
    result = [123 234 789]
```

Comment: You say it is a string and then store it as a vector. Please elaborate.

Comment: Are you having trouble removing a substring, or calculating where to cut?

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string S = "123xyzxyz1234";
  std::string s = "123";

  // The last instance of s starts from index p of S
  auto p = S.rfind(s);
  auto tail = S.substr(p + s.length());
  if (p != std::string::npos) {
    S.resize(p);
    S += tail;
  }
  std::cout << "S = " << S << std::endl;
}
```

The `if` statement guards against `not found` cases.

Comment: If `S` does not end with `s`  your function does not work correctly. E.g. for `S="123xyzxyz1234"` you return `"123xyzxyz"` instead of `"123xyzxyz4"`

Comment: Nice catch! I have edited the answer to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code shown is independent of any implementation details, I will give the brief overview of how to do this.

```
string S,s; // I am assuming they contain the right data
int position = S.rfind(s);
string ans1 = S.substr(0, position);
string ans2 = S.substr(position + s.length());
return ans1 + ans2;
```

There might be off by one errors in the code above, and some safety checks may be required. But I'm leaving that to you.

Comment: I don't think `find_last_of` is the function you want here. Perhaps [`rfind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind) is the functionality you were intending.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Thanks for that. Yea, I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

If none of your character from second substring is not repeating again before the last part of your substring, this will work:

```
   std::string S ="123234789123";
    std::string s="123";
    auto it= S.find_last_of(s[0]);
    std::cout<<S.substr(0,it);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string removeLastSubstr(string S, string s)
{
    reverse(S.begin(), S.end());
    reverse(s.begin(), s.end());

    if (s.find(s) != string::npos)
        S = S.substr(S.find(s) + s.size(), S.size());

    reverse(S.begin(), S.end());
    return S;

}
```